# Repeating a shorter Numpy array to a longer array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given two 1-d numpy arrays:

```
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> b = np.arange(2)
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> b
array([0, 1])
```

How can I add them such that the values of `b` are added to values of `a` as if `b` was repeated five times? This kind of thing is automatic in R but seemingly not in Numpy:

```
>>> a+b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,) (2,)
```

Best I can come up with is to tile `b` to make it the right size, but this seems clunky (especially the integer division...):

```
>>> a + np.tile(b, a.shape[0]//b.shape[0])
array([ 0,  2,  2,  4,  4,  6,  6,  8,  8, 10])
```

assuming the length of `b` divides the length of `a`, is there a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative solution is to use implicit broadcasting:

```py
(a.reshape(-1, b.shape[0]) + b).reshape(-1)
```

Note that reshape operations are cheap (there is no copy made).
Note that `a.shape[0]` must still be divisible by `b.shape[0]` like the tile-based solution.

Comment: Thanks. I thought maybe I'd missed a method in the docs that would do this, given an array, an axis, and another array to repeat it out to. This seems to be optimal though!